# NodeJS mongoDB get ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I need to make a small website that is query my local mongodb. All should just work fine on localhost. Therfore i desided to start with NodeJS. So all javascript functions are working fine when i just run them seperate, but if I call this functions via my html-code I getting a `ReferenceError: require is not defined` and later on a `TypeError: MongoClient is undefined`

So for your understanding i will post few lines of code:

1. My script-Import in html:

   ```html
   <script src="scripts/queryDB.js"></script>
   ```
2. My button

```html
<button onclick="startQuery()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
   <i class="material-icons">search</i>
</button>
```

If you need more information about my html please ask.

3. My javascript file

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

function oneResult(parkhausName, jahr, monat, tag, minuten) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("nosqlvl");
        var query = { parkhausName: parkhausName, 'datetime.year': jahr, 'datetime.month': monat, 'datetime.day': tag, 'datetime.time': minuten};
        dbo.collection("parkhaus").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

function startQuery(){
    alert("Really start?");
    oneResult("LANXESS arena 1", "2018", "1", "2", 680);
}
```

So I am dont know what the problem is, but maybe one of you can help me out. Please excuse the bad english on some point. Thank You

Comment: You need a backend to connect to mongo. You shouldn't do it from the UI. As for a tutorial, you can try
https://medium.com/netscape/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-1-18691663ea96

Answer (score 0):

require is not supported by browsers by default.

<del>You can use something like RequireJS</del>

Actually, you can't and shouldn't. The `mongodb` driver is not designed to work in browsers. This is because, usually, you don't send queries directly from the website to the database.

Instead, you should have a nodeJS http server running, which can receive HTTP request from the frontend, then query the database like you already did, and send the result back to the frontend.

I suggest using `express` and `ajax`, as described in [this](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-03-02/creating-a-simple-restful-web-app-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb) tutorial.

Comment: Tahnks for answering. I am pretty new to the field WebApp. So may you can recomment some tutorials how I can use the browser-js in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use AJAX requests? You can find more here : [Ajax requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) . Usually, when you want to connect the frontend with the backend, you should use ajax requests.